# Debezium Server and using variables in the application.properties file

Tags: debezium, change-data-capture

I'm trying to get Debezium Server running so that I can use GCP (Google) PubSub, and not have to use Kafka and the Kafka connectors.  I have it mostly running, however, I'm having trouble with the using variables in the tranforms section to define a Topic name.

According to the [documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.6/transformations/outbox-event-router.html#outbox-event-router-property-route-topic-replacement), when using the Outbox transformation, I can choose the Topic name by using the variable `${routedByValue}` for the setting `route.topic.replacement` and this will use the value that is determined by the setting `route.by.field`.  If the replacement setting is omitted, it will use a default topic name of `outbox.event.<route.by.field value>`.

When I try to use this variable in the 'application.properties' file ...

```
debezium.transforms.outbox.route.by.field=aggregate_type
debezium.transforms.outbox.route.topic.replace=${routedByValue}
```

... the Debezium Server stops with a `NoSuchElementException`, saying it cannot expand `routedByValue`.  If I omit that setting, it works fine and defines the topic name as `outbox.event.<route.by.field value>`.

How can I use this variable correctly in the 'applications.properties' file so I can customise the topic name (e.g. `route.topic.replace=myservice.${routedByValue}`)?

Answer (score 1):

The way I got this to work was to do the following ...

```
debezium.transforms.outbox.route.by.file=aggregate_type
debezium.transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement=$1
```

I believe this works because omitted from the config is another setting - `debezium.transforms.outbox.route.topic.regex` - and this has a default value of - `(?<routedByValue>.*)`.

If I understand the documentation correctly, the `$1` refers to the first group in the regex expression.  In my case, this will return whatever the value of `aggregrate_type` equates to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debezium Server 2.1 with Pulsar as sink type and the @Dazfl answer solve my issue !

```
debezium.transforms=outbox
debezium.transforms.outbox.type=io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter
debezium.transforms.outbox.route.topic.replacement=outbox.event.transactions.$1
```

Although the Debezium Server docs says to use $routedByValue, this do not works as expeceted...